# Alternatives to URI for passing arguments using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

is there any way you can pass variables in CI without using the uri. for example other than sending the variables to a uri like this:

index.php/user/search/name/joe/location/UK/gender/male

is there any other way to pass variables and not using the URI?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Session Class: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Setting the data:

```
$user = array(
    'name'     => 'joe',
    'location' => 'UK',
    'gender'   => 'male'
);

$this->session->set_userdata($user);
```

Getting the data:

```
$name = $this->session->userdata('name');
... etc.
```

You can also store the data in a cookie:

See: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` or `$_SESSION` instead of `$_GET` :-)

Answer (score 0):

$_POST or $_SESSION and if only want to set some messages you can use $this->session->set_flashdata('SOME_KEY','Logged in or blah blah'); CI sends it to the next page using its session class